# How to access camera preview frames with MediaCapture class in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, media, capture

I am trying to access camera preview frames of Hololens in a script of a Unity application, but I have some problems. I want to access the camera preview with MediaCapture class. I know that it is posible in a UWP application but I want to do it in Unity. 
In the UWP application need to create a CaptureElement in the XAML page and after that to set the source of this element, like that:

```
captureElement.source = mediaCapture;
mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

But in a Unity application I don't know how to create a CaptureElement or if it is possible.
How can I access the preview in this case? Or how to create a CaptureElement in Unity? Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!